# BibLaTeX – "In" text in bibliography doesn't get translated

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, translate

I am trying to write a report in french for a chemistry class, but for some reason, when I try to cite a book, the "in *book name*" doesn't get translated:

[image: "in" not translated]

Here's my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{rapport.bib}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{chimie02}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and `rapport.bib` contains:

```
@inbook{chimie02,
author = {Frank, Mustoe and Clancy, Christina and Doram, Ted},
booktitle = {Chimie 11 STSE},
title = {Déterminer la formule chimique d'un hydrate},
year = {2011},
publisher = {Chenelière McGraw-Hill},
pages = {286-287}
}
```

It does this with IEEE, APA, and MLA (I haven't tested other ones). I am currently running MiKTeX 2.9. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Try adding `\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{ in = {<whatever>} }`

Comment: @nicoco007: Note `in` doesn't have to be translated: it' not the English word that's used, but the Latin preposition, and it is traditional in French bibliographies.

Comment: @Bernard Oh. I wasn't aware of that. Interesting. I'll have to tell my teacher, since he got annoyed because it said *in* instead of *dans*.

Comment: Any ‘bibliophile’ knows that… ;o)

Comment: I'm far from being one of those (and I doubt my teacher is one)! I'm a newbie to the world of citing, references, and everthing related :P

Comment: @clemens Could you write an answer? I put my own for now but it would make more sense for you to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by [clemens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049) in the comments:

> Try adding `\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{ in = {<some text>} }`

(in French, replace *<some text>* with *dans*).

Also, as [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908) pointed out

> Note in doesn't have to be translated: it's not the English word that's used, but the Latin preposition, and it is traditional in French bibliographies.

So, technically, this word doesn't have to be translated.

Comment: It is more usual to ask somebody who commented to write an answer so they can get credit for helping you. By answering yourself, you are claiming the credit for their contributions.

Comment: @cfr Sorry, I didn't think about that! Will do.